# Working with results from CURL call XML

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

I have been working with some code for many hours today, wondering if someone could point me in a better direction than I'm going now.

I have PHP code that is fetching an array of data by sending XML via send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content).

My function:

```
function send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content)
{
$posturl = "https://" . $host . $path;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($content),
    );


$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soap:Body>
                <GetLocations xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                    <AuthLogin>ClientName</AuthLogin>
                    <UserName>MyUser</UserName>
                    <Password>SomePassword</Password>
                </GetLocations>
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>';

$response = send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content);
```

---

EDIT:

I'm getting closer, I implemented Baba's code and now getting a different error:

Warning: Unknown: Node no longer exists in....

I have the same code from above, with this now processing the response:

```
if ($response)
{

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$path = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body");
$path = $path[0] ;
foreach($path->GetLocationsResponse->GetLocationsResult->SearchLocations->children() as $table)
{
echo $table->Table->LocationName . "<br>";
}
```

Here's the true XML returned - I noticed Firebug made all the XML lowercase, whereas the source code has capitals mixed in which I think might matter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetLocationsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetLocationsResult>
<SearchLocations>
<Table>
<LocationName>
</Table>
<Table>
<LocationId>103501</LocationId>
<LocationName>Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA</LocationName>
</Table>
<Table>
<LocationId>101600</LocationId>
<LocationName>Atlanta, Georgia, USA</LocationName>
</Table>
</SearchLocations>
</GetLocationsResponse>
</GetLocationsResult>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you got is not `HTML` but `XML` but it looks like Your XML is wrong there is an invalid tag or you must have made mistake ... see

```
  <LocationName>Hawaii</Location>
                             ^--- it should be LocationName
```

It should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <getlocationsresponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
            <getlocationsresult>
                <SearchLocations>
                    <Table>
                        <LocationID>10322</LocationID>
                        <LocationName>Hawaii</LocationName>
                    </Table>
                </SearchLocations>
            </getlocationsresult>
        </getlocationsresponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Read This XML

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$path = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body");
$path = $path[0] ;
foreach($path->getlocationsresponse->getlocationsresult->SearchLocations->children() as $table)
{
     echo $table->LocationName . "<br>";
}
```

Output

```
 Hawaii
```

**------ Edit --------**

Your new XML is wrong again .. this is what it should look like http://codepad.org/JgJfqnrA

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and the info. I actually worked on it the night you replied but had some trouble - getting a different error, so I might need to adjust my syntax - I will try some things and post back.  Thanks again!

Comment: Added some updates. I think I'm pretty close, it's complaining about the node not existing now.  I'm not sure how those <TABLE> tags affect how I'm trying to output the XML.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @916 Networks am not sure if you want to me to fix all dirty work for you ... `so I might need to adjust my syntax - I will try some things and post back.` you did not have the decency to accept now you want more ???

Comment: sorry if I offended, I thought i had to wait until I had working code to accept?  I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: its ok ... What exactly is the issue you are having so that i can resolve it instantly

Comment: @916 Networks your new XML is wrong again .. this is the way it should loop like  http://codepad.org/JgJfqnrA

Comment: Thanks Baba - trying it out now.  I see how the logic should work now, it's making more sense, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: For anyone's future reference, the code Baba provided is solid!  I am still having trouble for some reason on my side (have to analyze the XML to ensure it's getting returned correctly), but when I put in the code from Baba it works perfect.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also for reference, my issue above is that there is something wrong with the XML returned by the call.  I'm getting a blank line from the host which is causing errors.  I used str_replace to remove the code and those errors are gone.  However, my XML starting with <Search Locations> actually comes out as &lt;SearchLocations&gt;
 in the HTML Source instead of XML, so something is off.

Comment: If the XML is malformed there is a way you can fix it see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956171/1226894 to show you how to use Tidy to fix the XML errors

Answer (score 1):

Baba is correct, the built in functions for parsing XML are the best way to do this but you could also use regex if the XML is really sent back with mismatching tags.

```
function regex_all( $capture, $haystack, $return=1 ) {
  preg_match_all( "#$capture#", $haystack, $match );
  return $match[ $return ];
}

foreach( regex_all('<LocationName>(.*?)<\/', $data) as $locationName ) {
  echo "$locationName<br>";
}
```

This would not be the preferred method because the regex isn't as reliable.