# How to parse an XML ignoring errors with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

Often my .xml document contains errors. I would want to parse my document anyway up to errors or try to fix errors automatically. Is that possible?

I have tried this, but it isn't working

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", array(LIBXML_NOERROR, LIBXML_ERR_NONE));

    if (!$xml) {
        echo "Failed loading XML\n";
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            echo "\t", $error->message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Your script only outputs the errors. I don't see anything you do to actually fix something here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From PHP DOC [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) options should be int not array

Replace

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", array(LIBXML_NOERROR, LIBXML_ERR_NONE));
                                                       ^------- You are using array
```

With

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE);
```

Instead of suppressing this errors you can as well fix the xml with [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) package.

Example **bad.xml**

```
<Family>
    <name>Hankre</name>
    <adults>2</adults>
    <kids > 16 </kids>
    <food>
        <tag>Nice </tag>
        <tag>Food </tag>
        <tag />
```

Fix XML

```
$config = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'clean' => true,
    'input-xml'  => true,
    'output-xml' => true,
    'wrap'       => false
    );

$tidy = new Tidy();
$xml = $tidy->repairfile($badXML, $config);
echo $xml;
```

Output

```
<Family>
    <name>Hankre</name>
    <adults>2</adults>
    <kids>16</kids>
    <food>
        <tag>Nice</tag>
        <tag>Food</tag>
        <tag />
    </food>
</Family>
```

Comment: ok, but the XML doesn't be parsed because SimpleXML got errors. I'd want to be parsed at least up to first error. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: yes .... that is entirely something different but it can be done .. you want it here or make it a new time so it would benefit others