# How to ignore SimpleXML errors when trying to prettify XML string output

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a question that is similar to previously asked thread like this one: [How to parse an XML ignoring errors with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954771/how-to-parse-an-xml-ignoring-errors-with-simplexml/12956171#12956171)

I already made code to make XML output nicely indented using SimpleXMLElement and playing with strings and it works when I have valid XML, however I get an error whenever I get bad xml file...

example:

```
fafjdsj kfčasdkf dflčakč <?xml .... ENVELOPE> dsjkaljdlk <?xml .. fdsfsa.. ENVELOPE> sdfadf
```

So basically I have a mixed string of multiple xml's in one and between xml's some random words (can be inside xml or between the two like in the example...)

Is there any possible solution for this?

My code (https://jsfiddle.net/72ygv2sb/):

```
<?php
$xml = 'opdfeakfjlčfkajf laesfa lfje akljč <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>dsfsadf<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope> faskfjasdf jdalkfj sdklfa alk <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>dsfsadf<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';


function xmlpp($xml, $html_output=false) {   

    #$xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*\n<"', $xml)); 

    $xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $level = 4;
    $indent = 0; // current indentation level
    $pretty = array();

    // get an array containing each XML element
    $xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*</', ">\n<", $xml_obj->asXML()));

    // shift off opening XML tag if present
    if (count($xml) && preg_match('/^<\?\s*xml/', $xml[0])) {
        $pretty[] = array_shift($xml);
    }

    foreach ($xml as $el) {
      if (preg_match('/^<([\w])+[^>\/]*>$/U', $el)) {
          // opening tag, increase indent
          $pretty[] = str_repeat(' ', $indent) . $el;
          $indent += $level;
      } else {
        if (preg_match('/^<\/.+>$/', $el)) {            
          $indent -= $level;  // closing tag, decrease indent
        }
        if ($indent < 0) {
          $indent += $level;
        }
        $pretty[] = str_repeat(' ', $indent) . $el;
      }
    }   
    $xml = implode("\n", $pretty);   
    return ($html_output) ? htmlentities($xml) : $xml;
}

echo '<pre>' . xmlpp($xml, true) . '</pre>' ; 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to actually make use of SimpleXML at all, because unless I'm reading it wrong, you effectively run `$xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); $xml = $xml_obj->asXML();`. Can't you just remove that, and run your regexes directly on the original not-really-XML string?

Comment: It has to be XML string as we pull xml data from server as a string

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. I'm saying you can replace `$xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*</', ">\n<", $xml_obj->asXML()));` with just `$xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*</', ">\n<", $xml));`. What is the purpose of `$xml_obj` in this code?

Comment: Ah, yea I can replace it, doesn't make any difference tho..I will still get an error if xml is not valid

Comment: Where will you get an error? If you're never using `$xml_obj`, you don't need to run `new SimpleXMLElement`; if you don't run that, there's nothing to raise any errors.

Comment: Erased it and I can see everything now, forgot to edit.. that you so much for clearing that out for me IMSoP..

Answer (score 0):

Question solved by IMSoP

replaced 
$xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*\n<", $xml_obj->asXML()));

with $xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*\n<", $xml));.

Removed $xml_obj variable completely. Getting full nicely editted xml now even tho it has errors in it